# How do I determine what is the source of Input Device in android?

Tags: java, android, bit-fields

I have to work with the [InputDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice.html).getSources() method to determine the type (source) of InputDevice. But instead of returning a predetermined integer, it returns a combined bitfield, for example: 16786707 (this is an actual value from my gamepad).

As you can see 16786707 is not listed in the [InputDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice.html) documentation page because it is generated on the fly. How do I parse the number 16786707 to determine whether the InputDevice is: a [SOURCE_CLASS_JOYSTICK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice.html#SOURCE_CLASS_JOYSTICK) (16), or a [SOURCE_GAMEPAD](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice.html#SOURCE_GAMEPAD) (1025), or [SOURCE_JOYSTICK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice.html#SOURCE_JOYSTICK) (16777232). My goal is to determine in a initialization method if the InputDevice is a gamepad like the Xbox 360 gamepad or any other gamepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                bytes          int        name
-------------------------------------------------------------
1000000000010010100010011  //16786707 <- Device
                    10000  //16       <- SOURCE_CLASS_JOYSTICK
              10000000001  //1025     <- SOURCE_GAMEPAD
1000000000000000000010000  //16777232 <- SOURCE_JOYSTICK
```

The device is a GamePad, a Joystick, and a class_joystick (guess that means its a joystick).

You'll need to use AND to check what:

```
int device = 16786707;
boolean is_source_class_joystick = ((device & SOURCE_CLASS_JOYSTICK) == SOURCE_CLASS_JOYSTICK);
boolean is_source_gamepad = ((device & SOURCE_GAMEPAD) == SOURCE_GAMEPAD);
boolean is_source_joystick = ((device & SOURCE_JOYSTICK) == SOURCE_JOYSTICK);
```

This should work.

Edit: I also checked, it can also be considered a keyboard and a mouse.