# HTC ONE M7 is considered as GamePad

Tags: android, gamepad

I developer a APP Android which can detect the type of device (smartphone normal or gamepad). 
I've done a test in HTC ONE M7 without the connection with a gamepad.
But my code tell me that it's a gamePad.

This is my code:

```
InputDevice dev = InputDevice.getDevice(deviceId);
int sources = dev.getSources();
// Verify that the device has gamepad buttons, control sticks, or both.
if (((sources & InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD) == InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD) || ((sources & InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK) == InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK))
{
     Log.d(TAG, "device detected : Game Pad");
}
```

And for HTC ONE M7's deviceID = 2, I found that the ((sources & InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD) == InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD) is true. That's why HTC is considered as a GamePad.

Anyone knows Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

We should check the existence of a GamePad like this: (&& instead of ||)

```
InputDevice dev = InputDevice.getDevice(deviceId);
int sources = dev.getSources();
// Verify that the device has gamepad buttons, control sticks, or both.
if (((sources & InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD) == InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD) && ((sources & InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK) == InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK))
{
    Log.d(TAG, "device detected : Game Pad");
}
```

Because for a really GamePad, it contains the InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD and InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK in the same time.

You can look this:
[How do I determine what is the source of Input Device in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278011/how-do-i-determine-what-is-the-source-of-input-device-in-android)

Thanks.